# why i am seeing this error while i clear textfield?

Tags: flutter

```
E/flutter (26755): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: visitChildElements() called during build.
E/flutter (26755): The BuildContext.visitChildElements() method can't be called during build because the child list is still being updated at that point, so the children might not be constructed yet, or might be old children that are going to be replaced.
E/flutter (26755): #0      Element.visitChildElements.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:7)
E/flutter (26755): #1      Element.visitChildElements (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3710:6)
E/flutter (26755): #2      GetNavigation.overlayContext (package:get/get_navigation/src/extension_navigation.dart:1148:40)
E/flutter (26755): #3      SnackbarController._configureOverlay (package:get/get_navigation/src/snackbar/snackbar_controller.dart:91:36)
E/flutter (26755): #4      SnackbarController._show (package:get/get_navigation/src/snackbar/snackbar_controller.dart:331:5)
E/flutter (26755): #5      GetQueue._check (package:get/get_utils/src/queue/get_queue.dart:42:47)
E/flutter (26755): #6      GetQueue.add (package:get/get_utils/src/queue/get_queue.dart:29:5)
E/flutter (26755): #7      _SnackBarQueue._addJob (package:get/get_navigation/src/snackbar/snackbar_controller.dart:357:31)
E/flutter (26755): #8      SnackbarController.show (package:get/get_navigation/src/snackbar/snackbar_controller.dart:63:27)
E/flutter (26755): #9      ExtensionSnackbar.snackbar (package:get/get_navigation/src/extension_navigation.dart:465:18)
E/flutter (26755): #10     Utils.snackBar (package:onlinefooddelivery/presentation/resources/components/utils.dart:6:11)
E/flutter (26755): #11     AppFormField.build.<anonymous closure> (package:onlinefooddelivery/presentation/login_screen/login_form.dart:32:17)
E/flutter (26755): #12     FormFieldState._validate (package:flutter/src/widgets/form.dart:526:43)
E/flutter (26755): #13     FormFieldState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/form.dart:589:13)
E/flutter (26755): #14     StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5583:27)
E/flutter (26755): #15     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5471:15)
E/flutter (26755): #16     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5634:11)
E/flutter (26755): #17     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5187:7)
E/flutter (26755): #18     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2895:19)
E/flutter (26755): #19     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:984:21)
E/flutter (26755): #20     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:457:5)
E/flutter (26755): #21     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1325:15)
E/flutter (26755): #22     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1255:9)
E/flutter (26755): #23     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1113:5)
E/flutter (26755): #24     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:312:13)
E/flutter (26755): #25     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:383:5)
E/flutter (26755): #26     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:283:31)
E/flutter (26755):
```

when i try to clear my text form field in flutter i got this error

Comment: Please provide code where you are rtrying to clear textFormField

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `Utils.snackbar` from within `FormFieldState.validate`. You can call it e.g. in text field's `onChanged` callback or from your submit button's `onPressed`.

This `Utils.snackbar` calls code that calls `visitChildElements` which cannot be run within the `build` method. `validate` callback [is called in `build` method](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/41456452f29d64e8deb623a3c927524bcf9f111b/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/form.dart#L582-L597).